Pagedjs and Angular integration
I'm trying to use Paged.js in Angular (v. 17).
I have to include a ployfill to make it work, but when I add it (either via angular.json or directly with a <script> tag in the head of index.html) an error message is shown in the console:

NG05104: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements.

And the app no longer works.
Any suggestions on this?

How did you add pagedjs to your Angular Project and was your project running before adding it? The error message sounds a little strange if it really is a problem with pagedjs...

I've added the library through npm install, and the script in the script array of the angular.json file. Adding the script gives the mentioned error; removing it, the app return running well.

@AndreaColleoni Have you found solution? Also struggling with adding page counter in print page

Not yet... I'm giving up to using the functionality (page numbers in my case) at the moment.

Found a stackblitz for this problem, which works for me.
